# can't open file with browser

Tags: python, file, browser, web-crawler

I wrote this web crawler program that accesses a website then it writes the output to an HTML file.

I have a problem with the following though. I am not able to open the output file with the web browser. However I can open URL's with the webbrowser module. Is it possible to open files using this method? If yes, how exactly can I do it?

```
import urllib
import webbrowser

f = open('/Users/kyle/Desktop/html_test.html', 'w')
u=urllib.urlopen('http://www.ebay.com')
f.write(u.read())
f.close()

webbrowser.open_new('/Users/kyle/Desktop/html_test.html')
```

Comment: The code works fine for me - the browser opens the file with html downloaded via `urllib`. Do you see any errors? What is happening?

Comment: Are you using windows or linux?
I'd suggest adding a file:// (making 3 slashes) in front (webbrowser.open_new('file:///Users/kyle/Desktop/html_test.html')

Comment: it's windows judging by the path :)

Comment: @PSS fair enough... I keep thinking Windows is still doing Documents and Settings as the start of the user's path ...

Comment: I am using mac 10.8, python 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python3, you should use urllib.request:

```
from urllib import request
filename = '/Users/kyle/Desktop/html_test.html'

u = request.urlopen('http://www.ebay.com')
with open(filename, 'wb') as f: #notice the 'b' here
    f.write(u.read())

import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new(filename)
```

Comment: (when i ran the code with inverted slashes i got this error) 16:17: syntax error: Expected “"” but found unknown token. (-2741)
118:119: syntax error: Expected “"” but found unknown token. (-2741)
117:118: syntax error: Expected “"” but found unknown token. (-2741)

Comment: @kylek, i am sorry - I guess it's not the seperator, if you are running mac.